# Rviz Interactive Marker Control Scaling

Tags: c++, rviz, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I change the scaling of the **controls** (i.e., the rings and arrows) of an interactive marker (in C++)? They are much larger than the marker itself. I want them to be at about the size of the marker.[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189024/rviz-interactive-marker-control-scaling/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on 2014-09-15**:
Why did you flag this question as "off-topic" in the end?

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-09-15**:
I actually flagged it as "off-topic or not relevant" because it is not relevant for me anymore (I found the answer) ;-)

**Comment by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on 2014-09-15**:
Please don't forget people googling your question, and getting frustrated by finding a... closed topic! Be community-friendly, answer your own question ;)

**Comment by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on 2014-09-30**:
Seriously did you find a way to scale these controls without scaling the meshes themselves? I really don't find how, there is no scale anywhere. Thanks by advance!

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-09-30**:
Ditto to @courrier. I reopened and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, in fact you won't find that inside the control but this is directly the visualization_msgs/InteractiveMarker.scale field!

---

Originally posted by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) with karma: 454 on 2014-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3